# How to call a 'debug' method in py.test in case of an failure?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am trying to write a `py.test` test with selenium to test a complex website. Because the setup is complex, the test can fail even before the actual test. But in such a case I want to be able to call a 'debug' function (maybe its a `teardown` function which I can use to debug things.

Example:

The test uses a fixture which returns a selenium webdriver

```
def test1(driver):
    driver.get("my page")
    ...
    other tests, login, etc etc
```

But now the call `driver.get` fails because of any reason. But in such a case I want to be able to investigate things like

```
def debug(driver):
    driver.screenshot(...)
    print(driver.page_source)
    ...
    driver.quit()
```

(including the shutdown of the driver, as the browser would stay open) with the same `driver` instance as has been used in the test method.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you not just use a `try-catch` and in the `catch` call `debug()`?

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part is to pass the test result into the fixture, the rest is pretty much trivial. Following the `pytest`s example [Making test result information available in fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures), add a custom hook in your `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep
```

Now you can enhance your `driver` fixture with custom teardown logic in case the test fails:

```
# test_selenium.py

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

def debug(driver):
    print('debug: ', driver.title)

@pytest.fixture
def driver(request):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    yield driver
    if request.node.rep_setup.passed and request.node.rep_call.failed:
        # this is the teardown code executed on test failure only
        debug(driver)
    # this is the teardown code that is always executed
    driver.quit()


def test_fail(driver):
    driver.get('http://wtf')


def test_ok(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.google.de')
```

Running the tests yields:

```
$ pytest -sv
=============================== test session starts ===============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.3, ...
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow/so-48521762, inifile:
plugins: ...
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_spam.py::test_fail FAILED                                              [ 50%]
debug Server Not Found

test_spam.py::test_ok PASSED                                                [100%]

==================================== FAILURES =====================================
____________________________________ test_fail ____________________________________

driver = <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver( ...
...
------------------------------- Captured log setup --------------------------------
remote_connection.py       474 DEBUG    POST http://127.0.0.1:50319/session { ...
...
remote_connection.py       561 DEBUG    Finished Request
======================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 7.23 seconds =======================
```